# Application for a UK visitor visa as an unemployed person?

Tags: visas, uk, algerian-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, algeria

Myself, my mother and my grandmother have been invited to visit the United Kingdom by my brother who lives there.

I am unemployed because I take care of my mother and grandmother, my grandmother supports me. I have a bank statement that shows that she gives me money for a long time but it doesn't show that is from her account, so I don't want to show my bank statement.

Is a letter signed by her stating that she supports me enough to support a visa application successfully?

Comment: What's the occasion giving rise to your invitation?

Comment: Note that you have to prove provenance of funds (that they are legally obtained etc) and also that your financial situation allows you to visit the UK without personal hardship - these are separate things that need to be proven.  The UK has no ability to force your grandmother (or anyone else) to continue to support you while in the UK, so your application may fail on that basis.  If your grandmothers bank statements show funds leaving and your statements show the same funds arriving in your account, a letter of explanation may serve to prove provenance.

Comment: Even if my brother he is our  sponcor whil in uk as is writing on the invitation, Is that mean i should not apply with them or what ?my grand motjer she is 87 years old and iam the one who cares about he. Do u advice me not to apply with them?

Comment: @DollMiss sponsorship doesnt actually guarantee anything at all.  As I said, the UK cannot force anyone, including the sponsor, to support you once you are in the UK, so your application has to also stand on its own merit.  You may have a stronger application as the carer for your grandmother, but only if your grandmother also has a strong application.

Answer (score 3):

As explained [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) by Gayot Fow, you have to show your bank statements. If you show nothing, they will assume that your finances look even worse than they do.

And you have to convince the UK that you **will** return to Algeria after your visit. Having more sponsors doesn't help to do that. Morey ties to the UK and fewer ties to Algeria are a reason for you to stay, after all.

It is not impossible that all of you will get visa. Think it through -- where does the money for the trip come, and what are you returning to. Can you explain why you will leave the UK without problems? Does you grandmother have investments, real estate, or a pension?

Comment: Problem is, someone elses assets and ties to their home country may not carry over to a separate individuals visa application very well, or at all.  If the 87 year old ends up in a UK hospital after a sudden decline in their condition, this person is going to have very little to return to Algeria for... and I doubt that UK immigration is going to bother itself with the last will and testament of a sponsor...

Comment: What if iaf a procuration of my grand mother account is that enough, and she is a pensioner of algerian money and euro witch means she has enough money to pay this trip and it shows on her bank history

Comment: @DollMiss, **they want to see your bank accounts.** It isn't just about the money to pay for the trip. It is about the whole picture of the applicants' situation.