# UK standard visitor visa for an unemployed mother

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, serbian-citizens

My mother and I have started a process of gathering documents to apply for a visitor visa for her to come and visit my husband and me.

She is a Serbian national and currently unemployed. However, she has her own apartment in her name where she lives with her boyfriend and has sufficient savings.
My husband and I are paying for all her travel costs and expenses while she is in the UK. Also have her flights booked.

Is this enough to prove that she will be going back after her visit? I am worried that her visa will be refused due to her unemployment.

Comment: *Also have her flights booked.* That's counterproductive

Comment: To clarify - have her flight to London and her RETURN flight booked.

Comment: They [don't want to see any flight bookings in the visitor visa application](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) (section 4)

Answer (score 4):

> **Is this enough to prove that she will be going back after her visit?**

No, at least it doesn't look that way to me.

The authorities will want to know how your mother supports herself, if she is unemployed, does she have other sources of income (pension, investment income, remittances from offspring, other).

They will want to know what ties she has to Serbia that will make it necessary for her to return there.

See https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide

> When you apply you’ll need to provide:
>
> - a current passport or other valid travel identification
> - evidence that you can support yourself during your trip, such as bank statements or payslips from the last 6 months

...

> You’ll need to provide the following:
>
> - the dates you’re planning to travel to the UK
> - details of where you’ll be staying during your visit
> - how much you think your trip will cost
> - your current home address and how long you’ve lived there
> - your parents’ names and dates of birth
> - how much you earn in a year
>
> You might also need:
>
> - details of your travel history for the past 10 years (as shown in your passport)
> - your employer’s address and telephone number
> - your partner’s name, date of birth, and passport number
> - the name and address of anyone paying for your trip
> - the name, address and passport number of any family members you have in the UK
> - details of any criminal, civil or immigration offences you have committed

---

Useful reading:

- [Application for a UK visitor visa as an unemployed person?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98051/application-for-a-uk-visitor-visa-as-an-unemployed-person)
- [UK visa refusal due to undefined source of fund after retirement](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74026/13639)
- [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/13639)

Comment: As I said, she has savings that she is living off at the moment. She has her own apartment and boyfriend that she lives with. To prove this we will submit apartment ownership contract in her name and also her bank has issued a confirmation of her savings.

Comment: I don't know what else to give them!

Comment: @user70035: From what you say, unless her savings are sufficient to live on for several years, it seems to me that her current circumstances may be insufficient to support an application for a normal tourist/visitor visa, even though (and partly because) you are paying for everything. I may be wrong, her application may go through OK, but to me it seems doubtful based on what you have written here. You may need to get professional advice from a UK solicitor with experience in UK visa applications.

Comment: Her savings are sufficient to keep her going for quite a few years actually. This trip is paid my husband and me as a Christmas present to her. Should I mention that in the invitation letter?

Comment: @user70035: I would but I suspect you need to also concentrate on what reasons she has to return to Serbia if her family is in the UK, she can access her savings from the UK and can probably sell her fixed assets in Serbia without insuperable difficulty. Why wouldn't she want to make the UK her home? Regardless, I think you need to wait for other answers or make your own judgement call or consult a professional.

Comment: With all due respect, if we're looking at it like that, how can a job stop someone from staying in the UK ? If someone really wanted to stay is a job really stopping them? Or family? Or property/ money? I mean... If they considered applications like that I doubt anyone would ever be granted a visa...

Comment: @user70035: I understand how you feel. My view is based on reading the dozens of questions and answers on this subject here, those are likely to be people with problems rather than people without problems - so my view may be overly pessimistic. I suggest filling in the application as best you can, following the UK government guidance. Give them a clear accurate picture of you and your mothers circumstances, they'll tell you if she is eligible for a visa or why not.